# How to Debug application in linux

Tags: linux, debugging

Recently I was at some interview for Linux SYS Admin position and I've got the question "How do you debug some application in Linux".

I am not new in Linux word and I actually stuck with this question.

I am aware about "top", "ps" command, but may be there are some other advanced commands.

I suggest that there is no one specific answer, but I think there is a couple of ways to do it.

Can any one provide some way 'How to debug some application'?.

Many thanks.

Comment: strace, gdb, /proc/<pid>/ ....

Comment: If you have the source code of that application (e.g. because it is free software), and if it is coded in C or C++ (etc...), you'll compile it with `gcc -Wall -g` and you'll debug it with `gdb`

Answer (score 0):

I would check the logs. I ll explain my self:

Top and ps provide a brief overview about the system resources the application is using. This is of course useful but, as I get it, debugging an application includes getting to know the function of this application (e.g what tasks it performs, and generally any information it provides).

The first thing I would check are application logs. And by logs I mean every type of logs (application specific - or system logs).

Gdb and strace in my opinion are low level tools, and are useful when an application has unexpected behaviour, receives some sort of errors, of if you want to reverse-engineer its function, check the system-calls hierarchy etc. But this is probably not the case.

Any serious application you will use as a sysadmin will provide sufficient amount of logs, either by setting a debug flag on, or by default.

So in sort, I would answer : 
*By checking logs* (syslogs and application logs)